# condaEnviromentError: cannot remove current enviroment . deactivate and run conda remove again

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I tried to uninstall conda enviroment base by typing below,

```
conda env remove -n base
```

As suggested i tried to deactivate base by using

```
conda deactivate base
```

Again I tried to remove that enviroment but again throws same error

***CondaEnviromentError: cannot remove current enviroment. deactivate and run conda remove again***

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear there is a way to remove the base environment. However, you can roll back revisions within in `conda`. You can list the revisions of your base environment by using `conda list --revisions`. From there you can roll back to previous revision of the environment by using `conda install --revision <REVNUM>`.

If you want to reset the environment to as close as you can get from the initial install run `conda install --revision 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `conda deactivate`
`conda remove -n env_name --all`

Comment: This generally works for conda environments, but it does not work for the `base` environment, which cannot be removed.